# How to prevent on page load XHR and activate it by a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I can't solve this problem so the XHR is activated when the page loads so I don't want that so I have this script that contains toggle I no longer want toggle associated to this script any more and I don't want to rely on CSS display none to hide the XHR result on page

load. But what I do want is on click the XHR is executed by me pressing the button which in effect gets the JSON contents which results in the XHR being executed.

Here's a gif image to better illustrate the problem.

The link:

[image: The link]

Here's the code.

**index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var z = $('.z'); // Grab class z to toggle
  var x = $('#x');
  var output = '';
  $.getJSON("x.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
      for (var j in element) {
        output += element[j] + '<br>';
      }
    });
    x.html(output);
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    z.toggle(); // Toggle z on button click
  });
});
  </script>
  <style>
  h1 {
  color: gold;
}

#x {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.z {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: none;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="z">
<h1>Details </h1>
<h2 id="x"></h2>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**x.json**

```
{
    "shop": [{
            "item": "Ps3",
            "cost": "$150"
        },
        {
            "item": "xbox 360",
            "cost": "$140"
        },
        {
            "event": "Black Friday",
            "date": "4-25-2018"
        },
        {
            "special_guest": "John Doe",
            "time": "4:30 pm"
        }
    ]
}
```

I assume that there is no feature on stackoverflow that offer's a AJAX editor to better illustrate this problem. So this is the best I can do to illustrate what i'm dealing with right now.

Comment: So pull the ajax request out and call it onclick? No clue what you are really asking.

Comment: Yes because it's a performance drain  if I have a lot of those on a page load that's why I want a to use a button to execute that .

Comment: So you could not pull it out into a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your XHR in a function:

```
var XHR = function(){
  $.getJSON("x.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
        for (var j in element) {
          output += element[j] + '<br>';
        }
      });
      x.html(output);
   });
};
```

And you can call the function on button click:

```
$("button").click(function(){ XHR(); });
```

Comment: Yes. Give it a try

Comment: Thank you so much Ben Rondeau your the best! it works!

Comment: Hey Ben Rondeau can you help my friend out he said your code haves problems in this post i'm trying to help him out so we can both use this script with out unwanted outputs and we don't want to try any suggestions from that post since we feel like it won't fit our needs we want more options  here's the post link my friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250415/how-to-stop-an-object-from-generating-additonal-copies-of-the-same-content/46251133#46251133