# How to stop an object from generating additonal copies of the same content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Every time when I press the button it keeps outputting the same data additionally. I don't want that because I don't want my users on my website to accidentally press the button again and notice another copy of the same data being outputted again so how do I prevent that.

Here's a GIF animated example what I mean.

[image: Visual example]

and here's the code i'm talking about.

**index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var z = $('.z'); // Grab class z to toggle
  var x = $('#x');
  var output = '';
  var XHR = function(){
  $.getJSON("x.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
        for (var j in element) {
          output += element[j] + '<br>';
        }
      });
      x.html(output);
   });
};
  $("button").click(function(){ XHR(); });
});
  </script>
  <style>
  h1 {
  color: gold;
}

#x {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.z {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="z">
<h1>Details </h1>
<h2 id="x"></h2>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**x.json**

```
{
    "shop": [{
            "item": "Ps3",
            "cost": "$150"
        },
        {
            "item": "xbox 360",
            "cost": "$140"
        },
        {
            "event": "Black Friday",
            "date": "4-25-2018"
        },
        {
            "special_guest": "John Doe",
            "time": "4:30 pm"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can keep some kind of a flag once your XHR function has been completed and in subsequent calls, you can ignore the XHR function if the flag is already set to true. This will prevent it from running multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You continously append to output.

Just change

```
var output;
var XHR = function() {
  output = "";
  ...
```

Like this

```js
$(function() {
  var z = $('.z'); // Grab class z to toggle
  var x = $('#x');
  var output;
  var XHR = function() {
    output = "";
    var data = {
      "shop": [{
          "item": "Ps3",
          "cost": "$150"
        },
        {
          "item": "xbox 360",
          "cost": "$140"
        },
        {
          "event": "Black Friday",
          "date": "4-25-2018"
        },
        {
          "special_guest": "John Doe",
          "time": "4:30 pm"
        }
      ]
    }
    $.each(data.shop, function(index, element) {
      for (var j in element) {
        output += element[j] + '<br>';
      }
    });
    x.html(output);
  };
  $("button").click(function() {
    XHR();
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: gold;
}

#x {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.z {
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="z">
  <h1>Details </h1>
  <h2 id="x"></h2>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to run the click handler only the first time.

```
$("button").one("click", XHR);
```

Comment: I had used that before it doesn't feel right to use it. Even do I know it will work but I don't like to feel limited to one click. Because you never know I would want to change the way this works in the future Look if I have to change my code enough to avoid using  $.one then ill do that I just need another solution.

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use $one() is because I can't hide the class call z. That's why I did't want to use that. Can you please offer me another solution.

Comment: @Rain What's wrong with checking whether the DIV is already filled in, as in A.Iglesias's answer?

Answer (score -1):

You have different options, some of them...

1. Disable the button once is pressed.
2. Remove the button once is pressed.
3. The "one()" solution proposed by barman (very clean).
4. Checking the content of "#x" before adding the content, just doing it if is empty.

All will work, and I would choose one depending on your interface and what it feels better for the user. Maybe make the button disappear is strange for your case, etc.

Also. if you want the function (XHR) to remain active, so maybe you want to reactivate it in some situation, then maybe 1, 2 or 4 are the way to go.

You can do all that inside the onclick event function or inside your XHR function. For example, for the 4 option...

```
$('button').click(function(){
    if ($('#x').html() != '')
        XHR();
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I dont want to disable the button I don't want to remove the button and I don't want to use $one() because I plan to add future features later on and I know that will complicate with that on what I might want to do in the future. I know there is other solutions out there and I don't want to use if else code sorry like I said if I have to change my code enough to avoid using all what you suggested then I will I know its dumb what I'm saying but I have my reasons why I simply want no copies of that out put at all simple as that regardless how many times I press the button I only want 1 output

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use $one() is because I can't hide the class call z. That's why I did't want to use that. Can you please offer me another solution.